# How can I set a breakpoint in LLVM's LowerTypeTests Pass?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to set a breakpoint in the LLVM code that generates jump tables in response to the `-fsanitize=cfi-icall` flag.

I have tried running indirect.c below through `clang -flto -fsanitize=cfi-icall indirect.c -o indirect`, and the resulting object file clearly contains jump tables in x86. Furthermore, the intermediate bitcode files emitted contain the string "CFI Canonical Jump Tables," which is only present in `llvm/lib/Transforms/IPO/LowerTypeTests.cpp` and  `llvm/tools/clang/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp`. However, I've built clang and opt from source with debugging symbols, and have not been able to hit the relevant code in either file in GDB or LLDB. The code is much more likely to be in `LowerTypeTests.cpp` since that's where jump table construction code occurs. Here's the code I'm using:

indirect.c:

```c
int foo (int a) {
        return 2 * a;
};

int bar (int a) {
        return 3 * a;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        int (*func)(int) = foo;
        int (*func2)(int) = bar;
        int c = func(2);
}
```

And the jump tables in the x86:

```
0000000000400510 <__typeid__ZTSFiiE_global_addr>:
  400510:   e9 6b ff ff ff          jmpq   400480 <foo.cfi>
  400515:   cc                      int3   
  400516:   cc                      int3   
  400517:   cc                      int3   

0000000000400518 <bar>:
  400518:   e9 73 ff ff ff          jmpq   400490 <bar.cfi>
  40051d:   cc                      int3   
  40051e:   cc                      int3   
  40051f:   cc                      int3
```

The relevant code in LowerTypeTests.cpp:

```
bool lowertypetests::isJumpTableCanonical(Function *F) {
  if (F->isDeclarationForLinker())
    return false;
  auto *CI = mdconst::extract_or_null<ConstantInt>(
      F->getParent()->getModuleFlag("CFI Canonical Jump Tables"));
  if (!CI || CI->getZExtValue() != 0)
    return true;
  return F->hasFnAttribute("cfi-canonical-jump-table");
}
```

and in CodeGenModule.cpp:

```
if (LangOpts.Sanitize.has(SanitizerKind::CFIICall)) {
    getModule().addModuleFlag(llvm::Module::Override,
                              "CFI Canonical Jump Tables",
                              CodeGenOpts.SanitizeCfiCanonicalJumpTables);
  }
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me trigger this code in GDB or LLDB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting a breakpoint in `clang`, first run your command with `-v` flag. It would give you proper incantation for `-cc1`:

```
"/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-freebsd12.0 ... <very long command line>
```

Pass this line to GDB and break wherever you like.